# Razorpay says seller cannot accept payments in (Live mode)

Tags: django, razorpay

> Im trying to implement razor pay in **live** mode on a **Django Project**, on clicking pay button it shows availabe options to pay, but when i select a option and proceed it says **this seller cannot accept payments**

```
razorpay_client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID,settings.RAZOR_KEY_SECRET))[This is my output image][1]
def cart(request):
l = len(Itemcart.objects.filter(uname=request.session['username'][0])) 
if request.session.get('username') and l >=1:
    CurrentUser = ""
    try:
        CurrentUser = request.session['username'][0]
    except:
        pass
    CheckOutPrice = 0
    try:
        for each in Itemcart.objects.all():
            CheckOutPrice = CheckOutPrice + int(each.icprice)
    except:
        print("Error! no cart data found for current user") 
    currency = 'INR'
    callback_url = 'paymenthandler/'
    Totalamount = int(CheckOutPrice * 100)
    razorpay_order = razorpay_client.order.create(dict(amount=Totalamount,currency=currency,payment_capture='0'))
    razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order['id']
    context = {}
    context['razorpay_order_id'] = razorpay_order_id
    context['razorpay_merchant_key'] = settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID
    context['amount'] = Totalamount
    context['callback_url'] = callback_url

    
    return render(request,'cart.html',context=context)
return render(request,'cart.html')


def paymenthandler(request):
print("123")
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
    
        # get the required parameters from post request.
        payment_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_payment_id', '')
        razorpay_order_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_order_id', '')
        signature = request.POST.get('razorpay_signature', '')
        params_dict = {
            'razorpay_order_id': razorpay_order_id,
            'razorpay_payment_id': payment_id,
            'razorpay_signature': signature
        }

        # verify the payment signature.
        result = razorpay_client.utility.verify_payment_signature(
            params_dict)
        if result is None:
            amount = Totalamount 
            try:
                # capture the payemt
                razorpay_client.payment.capture(payment_id, amount)
                # render success page on successful caputre of payment
                return render(request, 'paymentsuccess.html')
            except:

                # if there is an error while capturing payment.
                return render(request, 'paymentfail.html')
        else:

            # if signature verification fails.
            return render(request, 'paymentfail.html')
    except:
        # if we don't find the required parameters in POST data
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
else:
# if other than POST request is made.
    
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

> My script code in html

```
  <button type="button" id="pay-btn">Pay</button> #button
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"> 
  </script>
    <script>
    var options = {
    // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
    key: "{{ razorpay_merchant_key }}",

    // Amount is in currency subunits.
    // Default currency is INR. Hence,
    // 50000 refers to 50000 paise
    amount: "{{ amount }}",
    currency: "INR",

    // Your/store name.
    name: "{{ CurrentUser }}",

    // Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
    order_id: "{{ razorpay_order_id }}",
    callback_url: "{{ callback_url }}",
  };

  // initialise razorpay with the options.
  var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

  // add event listener to the payment button.
  document.getElementById("pay-btn").onclick = function (e) {
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault();
  };
</script>
```

*am i doing correct are is there a alternate way, i also tried using razorpay buttons but it cant accpt dynamic payments*

> error image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Lui.jpg

Comment: The issue is not in your code, if the Razorpay checkout is opening & payment flow starts, that means the technical side of integration is working fine. 

I would advise you to either 
1. Try the payment flow in **test** mode
2. Or, check your Razorpay dashboard at https://dashboard.razorpay.com and check whether or not your account is activated correctly. 
3. Or,  the last option contact Razorpay support and raise an issue with those folks.

Comment: yeah.. looks like i got issue in activating razorpay account.. thanks :)